# Git branch creation and deletion history

Tags: git, git-branch

I have a branch `foo` in remote (and locally) that is being periodically deleted and recreated. Is it possible to somehow see the history of this branch being deleted and created again?

Comment: What is the branch being used for? Specifically, is it being merged into any other branches and do those merge commits have a standardized message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not from a strict git perspective.

At branch creation, a reflog is created and associated with it, but it won't help finding branch creation/deletion times.

In some contexts it might be possible to infer branch creations and deletions by other means, like if the remote platform records and archives user actions, but no built-in way in git to get this information, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks! I will accept the answer later in rare case there might be another answer.

Comment: @Mikhail Of course! With a bit of luck, there is a way I didn't know about that could be used here.